# List all sums of k objects in set of n integers IN DESC ORDER

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have a large set of n integers. I need to choose k elements in that list such that they sum from largest to smallest. Every subset chosen will have to be valid for some rule (it doesn't matter the rule). I want to find the largest-summed subset that is also valid.

For instance, using a small set of numbers (10, 7, 5, 3, 0), a subset size of 3, and a simple rule (sum must be prime), the code would look at:

```
10, 7, 5 = 22 -> NOT PRIME, KEEP GOING
10, 7, 3 = 20 -> NOT PRIME, KEEP GOING
10, 5, 3 = 18 -> NOT PRIME, KEEP GOING
10, 7, 0 = 17 -> PRIME, STOP
```

I know I could just put EVERY combination in a list, order it descending, and then work my way down until a sum passes the test, but that seems hugely inefficient in both space and time, especially if I have a set of size like 100 and a subset size of 8. That's like 186 billion combinations that I'd have to calculate.

Is there a way to just do this in a simple loop where I start at the biggest sum check for validity, and then calculate and go to the next largest possible sum and check for validity, etc.? Something like:

```
// Assuming set is ordered, this is the largest possible sum given the subset_size
int sum = set.Take(subset_size).Sum();

while (!IsValid(sum))
{
    sum = NextLargest(set, subset_size, sum);
}

bool IsValid (int sum)
{
    return sum % 2 == 0;
}

int NextLargest (int[] set, int subset_size, int current_sum)
{
    // Find the next largest sum here as efficiently as possible
}
```

Comment: You can try to use a prefix sum for that, and store the sum of previous elements as current value

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to look at every combination, only the ones that sum to a larger number.

Iterate over the set in descending order and check the sum. Keep track of the largest valid sum found so far. When a larger sum is impossible, break out of the loop. For example, given subset size 5, you found a valid sum 53. At some point, you are considering a subset that starts with 10. Since the numbers are in descending order, the largest sum you can get at this point is 50. So this path can be abandoned. This should significantly trim down your solution space.